# How do I view my play site off a web server?

Tags: playframework

I have access to a web server and would like to view a play helloworld from my site.

I have..

1. Logged into my server.
2. Installed Play
3. Ran play new helloworld
4. Ran play run helloworld

If my normal site is

```
www.blah.com/index.html
```

-or

```
www.blah.com
```

found at

```
~/blah
```

and play and helloworld are located respectfully at

```
~/blah/play1.4.2/play1.4.2/
~/blah/helloworld/
```

What would I type at the browser bar to get the play welcome message?

Answer (score 1):

if you are running the new play app without any change in conf/application.conf, then you should be able to access it via `http://www.blah.com:9000`, note the default play app listen to port 9000, not 80. If you are running on your local server, then you should go `http://127.0.0.1:9000`

Comment: A regular link to the website is more like... `http://www.blah.org/blah/index.html`  That said `...index.html:9000` and `..org/blah:9000`  end in 404

Comment: Don't add 9000 in the end, add it only after blah.org: http://www.blah.org:9000/ and http://www.blah.org:9000/blah/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you installed Play in a remote machine. You should be able to access to the server using:

```
http://<ip>:9000/
http://<domain_of_machine>:9000
```

If you can't, most likely culprits are:

- IP tables blocking your request (9000 is not a standard port, it probably is closed)
- Any other firewall blocking that request
- Your machine uses Apache or another server to manage the web requests and it can't handle the request for Play. In this situation you could add an extra entry to redirect to the Play server